# TRUNCATE Partitions from table failed (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Log:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [Thread] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    [Level] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Logger] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [VARCHAR](4000) NOT NULL,
    [Exception] [VARCHAR](2000) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

The PK is `Id`, and we partitioned column `[Date]` after create an index on it and change PK to non-clustered:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Log] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Log_Date] 
     ON [dbo].[Log]([Date] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

The partitions are created successfully.

Now, we want to use Truncate to remove partitions:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Log]
WITH (PARTITIONS (1 TO 2));
```

But get this error:

> TRUNCATE TABLE statement failed. Index 'PK_Log' is not partitioned, but table 'Log' uses partition function 'myDateRangePF'. Index and table must use an equivalent partition function.

Does this mean partitioned table can only have one index? if the existing table has multiple index, in order to truncate it, we have to remove all indexes first?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you created the index `PK_Log...ON [PRIMARY]`, which made it a non-partitioned index on a partitioned table. You'll need to drop that index (and any other non-partitioned indexes, probably) and recreate it. Either specify the partitioning filegroup explicitly, or leave the `ON` clause out and let SQL Server pick the filegroup. By default, it will create the index on the same filegroup as the underlying table and with the same partitioning as the table.

See [Partitioned Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#partitioned-indexes) in BOL for additional information.